# The progress bar start and never finished

Tags: progress-bar, next.js13

In my project, I am using Nextjs 13.4.8 version, with the package of "next-nprogress-bar", I am trying to make a progressbar for the route changing, so it works well when navigating from a page to another, just one problem, is that when trying to navigate to the same url of the page I am already on, the progressbar start working and fisnih its 100% state, andremains there, can you help please? thanks. This is the code of my platform/app/layout.js

```
"use client"
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import { AppProgressBar as ProgressBar } from "next-nprogress-bar";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })



export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        {children}
        <ProgressBar
          height="2px"
          color="#f00"
          options={{
            showSpinner: true,
            spinner: true,
            trickle: true,
            trickleSpeed: 10,
            shallowRouting: true,
            onComplete: () => {
              const peg = document.querySelector('#nprogress .peg');
              if (peg.offsetWidth === 100) {
                peg.parentNode.removeChild(peg);
              }
            },
          }}
        />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

[The problem visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGKR5.png)